# Wrong inequality in simple proof Cauchy $\implies$ Boundedness.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

These [notes](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/flynn/genus2/AnI0506/analysisI-wk6.pdf) from Oxford University contain an apparently very simple proof that Cauchy sequences (real or complex) imply boundedness.

I understand the Cauchy condition $|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$, and that the proof assigns $\epsilon=1$ as an arbitrary value.

**Question:** I can't understand how the following inequality is derived from the triangle inequality:

$$|a_m| \leq 1 + |a_N|$$

**My Attempt:** I have tried using the [reverse triangle inequality](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Epa/math/equations/proof.html) with no success:

$$|a_m| - |a_N| \leq |a_n -a_N| < 1$$

And so,

$$|a_m|  < 1 + |a_N|$$

Here the inequality is $<$ and not $\leq$ as per the reproduced notes.

---

For convenience, the proof is reproduced below.

[image]

Comment: If $a<b,$ then $a\leq b,$ so the distinction is moot.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have found several authors do this, .. do you know why it is not discouraged?

Comment: Because it doesn’t matter. @tariq

Comment: Downvote seems extreme to me.

Comment: was it the question or the comment that was downvoted?

Comment: @Tariq: You do not explicitly need the equality case here to show boundedness. Just showing $|a_m|$ is bounded above suffices, so it doesn't matter if you use $\lt$ or $\le$

Comment: Can’t say why it was downvoted, but it is a little unclear what the question actually is. There is nothing wrong with writing $a\leq b$ just because you can prove the stronger result $a<b.$ The decision to do so isn’t “wrong” in a technical sense, like if the book accidentally reversed an inequality.

Comment: There is no downvoting on comments here. It was the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with writing $a\leq b$ when you can prove that $a<b.$

For example, we can say:

$$1+x^2\geq 0,$$ even though we know $1+x^2>0.$

Saying that, for all $x,$ $$f(x)\leq g(x)$$ does not mean that for some $x_0,$ $f(x_0)=g(x_0).$ It also doesn’t mean that for some $x_1,$ $f(x_1)<g(x_1).$

It means literally “less than or equal to.”

That is, for every $x,$ either $f(x)<g(x)$ or $f(x)=g(x).$

It could be $<$ for every $x.$ It could be $=$ for every $x.$ Or it could be a mix. Or we might have no way of telling.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Assuming your sequence converges:
In case you're interested in a different, relatively-straightfoward argument: Say your sequence converges to $L$. Then all-but-finitely-many terms will be within $\epsilon$ of $L$. All these are contained in the finite ball $B(L, \epsilon)$ . Now you just need to consider the first $N$ terms; $N$ of course finite, so that the set $\{ a_1, a_2,..., a_N \}$ is bounded, say by $M$...Then you can find a ball of finite radius that containes all terms in the sequence.

Comment: That assumes a Cauchy sequence converges, which it doesn’t in all spaces, such as $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: Valid point. I wrongly assumed it was a sequence of Real numbers. Let me edit.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: notice OP refers to Real or Complex sequences , both Complete metric spaces, though.

Comment: The bounded theorem comes *right after* the definition of Cauchy sequence. Completeness of $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R$ are clearly unknowns, and probably not defined. And you never say in your answer why they converge, you just start by assuming the limit.